# How to convert POJO values to object array

Tags: java, reflection

I have pojo class as;

```
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int salary;
    // getter and setter
}
```

I want to convert value of this pojo class object to object array as;

```
Object[] perObjArray = new Object[4];
empObjArray[0] = personObjcet.getId();
empObjArray[1] = personObjcet.getName();
empObjArray[2] = personObjcet.getAddress();
empObjArray[3] = personObjcet.getSalary();
```

Like this scenario, i have other pojo classes. I want to create generic method where i can pass pojo object and it will return object array of those values.

I know we can use reflection, but not sure how ? Please help..

Comment: Why? This sounds like it might be an X-Y problem (i.e. there's a better way to solve the underlying issue you are trying to solve). Could you tell us *why* you'd rather have an object array rather than an appropriate object with fields?

Comment: I want to convert pojo object values to object array and then want to convert oracle.sql.STRUCT, just for learning purpose i know i can use hibernate.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this via reflection

```
public Object[] getObjectArray(Person person) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
   Field[] fields = person.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
   int fieldCount = fields.length;
   Object[] objArr = new Object[fieldCount];

   for (int i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
     Field field = fields[i];
     field.setAccessible(true);

     objArr[i] = field.get(person);
   }

   return objArry;
}
```

to do this via the getters you can do the following via reflection as well

```
public Object[] getObjectArray(Person person) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
   Method[] methods = person.getClass().getMethods();

   List<Method> getters = new ArrayList<>();
   for (Method m : methods) {
     if (isGetter(m)) {
       getters.add(m);
     }
   }

   Object[] objArr = new Object[getters.size()];
   for (int i = 0; i < getters.size(); i++) {
     Method m = getters.get(i);
     objArr[i] = m.invoke(person); 
   }

  return objArr;
}

public static boolean isGetter(Method method){
    if(!method.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith("get")) return false;
    if(method.getParameterTypes().length != 0)   return false;  
    if(void.class.equals(method.getReturnType()) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Make sure you do your necessary null checks and error handling.

The second method will get all your publically accessible getters in your class and invoke them to retrieve the value.

This also assumes all your getters start with "get" might have to adjust according to your needs.

Comment: It's probably better to call the getters instead of accessing the fields directly. Not only does it avoid having to use `setAccessible` but it allows reading anything that's exposed as a bean property and not just fields.

Comment: I added an edit that will use getter methods. Please see edit.

Comment: I changed it a little to add a method to make sure the selected method is an actual getter. IE starts with `get` and has no parameters and has a return type other than void.